# Ruby Code not in Any Method

Tags: ruby

General Ruby question:
In Ruby, I frequently see code that's inside a class, but not part of a method. For example:

```
class DooDad
   attr_accessor :foo
end
```

or

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :students
end
```

I think `attr_accessor` and `has_many` are methods getting invoked with the `:foo` or `:students` arguments, respectively, is that right? If so, when do these kinds of statements get executed. I tried this:

```
class DooDad
  attr_accessor :foo
  puts "I happened!"
  @foo = 7
end
```

It doesn't seem to run these a part of the `new` method:

```
dd = DooDad.new
dd.foo
```

outputs nil, and never spits out any `puts` stuff

How exactly does all that work?

Comment: They are executed when the class object DooDad gets created. In other words, when the file containing your class gets parsed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Methods like `attr_accessor` and `has_many` are often called "mimic methods" because they kinda look like ruby keywords (mimic them) but they're in fact, as you and others have correctly pointed out, method calls.

```
dd = DooDad.new
dd.foo
```

> outputs nil, and never spits out any `puts` stuff
>
> How exactly does all that work?

When you're inside of a class definition the implicit receiver of all method calls and "variable definitions" is `self`, which in your case is `DooDad`.

So when you're writing

```
class DooDad
  @foo = 1
end
```

you're actually defining an instance variable on `self`, that happens to be the class itself , since you're inside of that classes definition. (and outside of any other class, module or method definitions)

The method `attr_accessor` on the other hand generates, with some help of metaprogramming, accessor methods **for an instance variable of the objects that are instantiated from class `DooDad`**.

Back to your example:

```
class DooDad
  attr_accessor :foo
  puts "I happened!"
  @foo = 7
end
```

With the stuff mentioned above, you should now understand that you're dealing with two different @foo variables, one for instances of class DooDad (i.e `DooDad.new`), the other (the one you created by writing `@foo = 7`) for the class DooDad itself!

When calling the `new` method on a class, you create an instance of it.

```
dd = DooDad.new 
#=> dd is now an object of class DooDad

dd.foo 
#=> You just called the "getter" method for an instance variable foo of object dd, which was never defined before, that's why it's returning nil.
```

The `puts "I happened!"` statement, just as the other two in fact, gets evaluated as soon as the class is loaded, but not when you call `new` on it. 
If you want the behaviour you described (doing stuff when calling `new`), I suggest implementing an `initialize()` method for  `DooDad`, which will get called when you call `new`:

```
class DooDad
    attr_accessor :foo

    def initialize()
      puts "I happened!"
      @foo = 7
    end
end

dd = DooDad.new
#=> outputs "I happened!" and sets dd.foo = 7

dd.foo
#=> 7
```

But why does `@foo = 7` now set the instance variable of `dd` and not `DooDad`?
When you define a method with the keyword `def`, you enter a new scope (you pass a scope gate). `self` is now no longer the class, but instead an instance of that class, that you created with `new`, just like `dd`. So when you're writing `@foo = 7` inside of a method definition, you're talking about variables for an instance of class `DooDad`, not the class itself.

This post is probably way too long and might not even satisfy as an answer, but I hope it was somewhat comprehensive.

Comment: Great explanation indeed!

Answer (score 7):

Methods like `has_many` and `attr_accessor` are actually methods on the Module or Class. You are absolutely right about them being normal methods, invoked with arguments just like any other. When a method is called directly in the class (outside of a method definition), it is being called on the class itself.

Here are the docs for [attr_accessor](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor).

Answer (score -2):

They are syntactic sugar built into the language, so it is not the same as your test.  When you write (for example)

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
end
```

It is actually shorthand for...

```
class Foo
  def bar
    @bar
  end

  def bar=(value)
    @bar = value
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually he's right. `attr_accessor` is not syntactic sugar, it's a method of the Module class (http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html), and has_many is a method on ActiveRecord's association ClassMethods (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: @gmalette: Huh, I didn't know that, thanks.  In reality though it amounts to the same thing for most cases (I realize it may change metadata and whatnot).  Good to know.

Comment: I think the difference is that syntactic sugar is something that the interpreter adds to ease burdens in the language (who wants to say `object.method=(value)`?) But in this case, it's just a method invocation. That method in turn defines the setters and getters you show, but you could, for example, go write them yourself.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek: Right, I know what syntactic sugar is :). I was just saying that I didn't realize they were actually methods in Module, so I learned something new.  For most cases the result is the same, but it's good to know either way.