# Code placed outside of a method

Tags: ruby

In Java, every instruction executed is defined inside a method. In Ruby, you can do something like this:

```
class A
  puts "Inside of A class" # [1]
end
```

and [1] will be executed when `A` is loaded. An example of this is the following code in Rails:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :presence => true, length: 1..19, :uniqueness => true
end
```

What sense does it have to write code outside of a method? How can it be used (how can it be invoked)?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063190/ruby-code-not-in-any-method

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to know why you'd place code to execute "inside a class," when there's no way to have it execute more than once (when the class is first loaded.)

In Ruby, all classes are themselves objects - they are instance of the class `Class`. So what's happening under the hood when Ruby "reads" a class definition, is that Ruby is actually running methods on that instance of the class `Class`.

So a `def` inside the class definition of the class `A` is actually the same as `A.send(:define_method, ...)` - to understand what that means, you have to understand [what senders and receivers are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592268/how-to-understand-sender-and-receiver-in-ruby), and how they are implemented in Ruby. That SO post I linked to does a pretty good job of referring you to more material. The `def` syntax is just a convention to make the sending/receiving look like the syntax of other languages so that it's easier to "transition" to Ruby from other languages.

Ruby doesn't require that you should only call methods on the class itself when defining the class - so you can run any code you want. One use case is when you define a variable prefixed with an @ inside the class definition:

```
class A
  @class_var=123
  def self.class_var
    @class_var
  end
  def self.class_var=(inp)
    @class_var=inp
  end
end

a=A.new
b=A.new
b.class.class_var=5
puts a.class.class_var
# 5
```

Note the `def self.` notation that defines "class methods" - they can then access the "class variable" that you created by writing the code "inside the class."

This question comes up a lot for me, so [I've written a more extensive blog post about it](http://sameer.siruguri.net/blog/2013/11/18/ruby-metaclasses-what-are-they-good-for/), to try and go into more detail about how Ruby implements these concepts. I have written them here in scare quotes, because they mean slightly different things in Java and C++, so don't apply their meanings very directly to try and understand what they mean in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

> What sense has write code out of methods?

You've already seen it. Instead of changing the language itself (and the compiler) to add annotations to Ruby, the makers of Rails could make model validations easily (and lots of DSL for different things). Another example is `att_accessor`, a method that called in the context of a class will add accessor methods. And there are many many more.

Basically, you are adding that way lots of flexibility to the language.

> How it can be used (how can it be invoked)?

You already did in your example. Just put the code there... and it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use and invoke it like such:

```
def putString
  puts "Inside method outside of class"
end

class A
  puts "Inside of A class"    #[1]
  putString
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It gets invoked when you require the file.

Uses?

Meta-programming is one

```
['foo','bar'].each |m| do
  def m
    [m]
  end
end
```

There's an even sneakier scenario where you can put code outside of the class, never mind the method, confused the heck out me when I first saw it.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here refer to code inside a class and outside its methods. I think the OP asked about code outside everything - forbidden in Java!

Java mimics the C languages' compilation cycle. In C, only certain kinds of lines can happen during compilation. Then, only the remaining kinds of lines can run during execution.

In Ruby, code evaluates from top to bottom. The commands `class` and `def` essentially mean "capture all these tokens, and evaluate them later." So, because the entire file evaluates at runtime, things outside classes can happen very early.

The most notorious example is:

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper')
```

`require` is (prepare for a shock) just a method, and `File` is (prepare for another one) always available. So a Ruby programmer can exchange zillions of boring, fragile lines of configuration files (in Java ANT or C MAKE) for just a few ugly - but bullet-proof - lines of raw Ruby, at the top of each file.